# Get text baseline instead of BoundingBoxRect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm working on a React Component in which I render a `rect` element and a `text` element inside the `rect` one.

Also, I want to specify the vertical alignment of the `text` element: to achieve that, I've found the `dominant-baseline` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) attribute, which is perfect.
Too bad that `dominant-baseline` attribute doesn't work on IE11 nor Edge. To fix the problem, I thought I could manually adjust the position using the `dy` attribute, but here's the problem: using the `dominant-baseline` attribute, the browser considers exactly the text, not its bounding box.
For example, if I assign `hanging` to `dominant-baseline` attribute, and I position the `text` element `10px` from the top of the `rect` element, I obtain the following:
[image]

As you can see, `10px` from the `rect` is the distant between the top of the `rect` and the actual write of the label. Instead, if I would consider the `boundingBoxRect` of the `text` element, and I use it to position the `text` element `10px` from the top `rect` element, I have the following result:
[image]

First, I hope I've explained correctly what are the "assumption", then, my question: is there a way to retrieve the actual space occupied by the text? Something like `getTextBoundingBox`? Otherwise, I couldn't obtain the exact same result in Chrome/Firefox/Opera (where `dominant-baseline` works) and IE/Edge (where I would need to use the `dy` attribute with `getBoundingBoxRect()`)

Comment: You may try to use one of these methods: [SVGTextContentElement](SVGTextContentElement) I think `getStartPositionOfChar` may be interesting. Since your text is horizontal you may use the first character.

Comment: Thank for answer. Though, I tried with `getStartPositionOfChar()`, but no luck

Comment: Show me how did you do it. I would like to see your code. A simplified version of it.

Comment: I did not write any code, I just tried from the browser console with the element I had on the screen: `getStartPositionOfChar()` did return me the distance from SVG (0,0) coordinate to the bottom of the char (the actual char, not the boundingBox). But, it was more like the "baseline" of the char, since if I had the chars `"B"` and `"y"`, the y coordinate was the same, which is not quite true for what I'm looking for.